# Проблема с htacess в WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, reactjs, cms

Привет!Я создал фронт енд для своего сайта на React и залил его на сервер.На сервере в корне лежит сам проект а WordPress в папке wp.WordPress мне нежен только для того чтобы отправлять API фронту на React и добавлять товары в магазин.Когда я пытаюсь зайти в админку WordPress по URL `http://portlandwp.com/wp/wp-admin` я получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
потому что WordPress меняет путь на тот где нету папки wp.Я понимаю что мне нужно в htacess сделать редирект или изменить пути но почитав кодекс htacess WP я не понял как это сделать для WP.Можете показать как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress не работает из любого выбранного места. [Переносить сайт нужно правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562).

Лучше всего использовать плагин Duplicator, но раз уж вы перенесли все файлы, используйте скрипт [Database Search and Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Создайте папку в корне WordPress, в вашем случае `/wp/srdb`, поместите туда файлы скрипта. Наберите в браузере `http://portlandwp.com/wp/srdb/`. Произведите замену всех строк `http://portlandwp.com` на `http://portlandwp.com/wp`. Сайт должен начать работать.

А .htaccess оставьте стандартный, как [указано в codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Спасибо,все заработало:)